# Посчитать длительность, когда секунды и миллисекунды в отдельных переменных

Tags: c++, c

Есть структура tivemal, у которой два поля

```
long int sec;
long int usec;
```

Мне нужно от одной структуры timeval отнять другую и разделить на третью, то есть найти:
(timeval - timeval) / timeval

Comment: можно, в `long long` сконвертируйте `long long t = sec*1000 + usec` или как-то так и делайте что хотите :)

Comment: А можно в double, пересчитать как `sec + usec/1000.0`, потом обратно.

Comment: @pavel ну незнаю, у меня long int уже 8 байт, потери разрядности не будет?

Comment: @van9petryk я просто привык что `long` 4 байта. В `long double` тогда лучше переводите. Это 10 байт, как раз хватит. А у вас случайно нет типа `int128` или что-то такое.

Comment: long double у меня 16 байт. int128 найти не могу. ОС FreeBSD, архитектура 64 бита.

Comment: чисто для уточнения, но префикс `u` обычно используют для _микросекунд_. Собственно http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html: "long int tv_usec: This is the rest of the elapsed time (a fraction of a second), represented as the number of **microseconds**. It is always less than one million."

Comment: @MonahTuk я не совсем понял, что уточняет ваш комментарий? Множить tv_usec на 1 000 000?

Comment: @van9petryk именно! потому что это не миллисекунды (10^-3), а микросекунды (10^-6). Вообще и тему переименовать стоит. Для корректности.

Answer (score 2):

Имея следующую структуру:

```
struct CustomTime
{
    long long secs;
    long long msecs;
};
```

Разность делается довольно просто:

```
CustomTime difference(CustomTime first, CustomTime second)
{
    CustomTime res;
    res.secs = first.secs - second.secs;
    res.msecs = first.msecs - second.msecs;
    if(res.secs >= 0 && res.msecs < 0)
    {
        --res.secs;
        res.msecs += 1000;
    }
    else if(res.secs < 0)
    {
        if(res.msecs < 0)
            res.msecs = -res.msecs;
        else
        {
            ++res.secs;
            res.msecs = res.secs != 0 ? 1000 - res.msecs : res.msecs - 1000;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

А вот с делением не всё так просто. Т.к. возможно переполнение и мы используем `long long`, то нужно сокращать наши вычисления, а для этого как раз и существуют логарифмы. Методом проб и ошибок пришёл к такому методу:

```
CustomTime division(CustomTime first, CustomTime second)
{
    auto logMsec = log(first.secs + first.msecs / 1000.0) - log(second.secs + second.msecs / 1000.0);
    double logSecs = logMsec < log(1000) ? 0.0 : logMsec - log(1000);
    CustomTime res;
    if(logSecs < 0.000001)
    {
        res.secs = 0;
        res.msecs = exp(logMsec);
    }
    else
    {
        auto dSecs = exp(logSecs);
        res.secs = dSecs;
        res.msecs = (dSecs - res.secs) * 1000;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется прямая конвертация в `long double` даёт меньше погрешность.

Comment: @pavel, а как Вы можете конвертировать в `long double`? `long long * long long` может быть больше `long double`

Comment: ну например так `long double val = (long double) first * second;` А в смысле больше, максимум произведения меньше `2^128` (по `2^64`). `long double` много больше экспоненту допускает. А точность не хуже чем логарифмирование.

Comment: фактически при таком преобразовании мы потеряем только младшие биты, которые не влезут в мантиссу, или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @pavel, нет это я под конец дня притормаживаю, надо смотреть насколько в точности потеряет Ваш метод, проверите? Я свой проверял на нескольких вариантах — у меня всё получалось как надо.

Answer (score 0):

В одной секунде 1000 миллисекунд, значит есть 2 варианта:
1. Перевести все в миллисекунды и подсчитать.
2. находить функцию или перегрузить операторы "-" и "/".
https://habrahabr.ru/post/132014/

Answer (score 0):

Разность можно посчитать так

```
struct timeval
tm_diff (struct timeval tm1, struct timeval tm2)
{
  struct timeval diff;
  int neg = tm1.tv_sec < tm2.tv_sec ||
    (tm1.tv_sec == tm2.tv_sec && tm1.tv_usec < tm2.tv_usec);
  if (neg) { // SWAP
    diff = tm1;
    tm1 = tm2;
    tm2 = diff;
  }

  diff.tv_sec = tm1.tv_sec - tm2.tv_sec;
  if (tm1.tv_usec < tm2.tv_usec) {
    tm1.tv_usec += 1000000;
    diff.tv_sec--;
  }
  diff.tv_usec = tm1.tv_usec - tm2.tv_usec;
  if (neg)
    diff.tv_sec = -diff.tv_sec;

  return diff;
}
```

ну, а делить, наверное в самом деле лучше в `double`, переводя в микросекунды

```
double t1 = tm1.tv_sec + tm1.tv_usec * 1000000, t2 = tm2.tv_sec + ....;
```

P.S.

Безусловно, ошибся, умножать надо секунды...

```
double t1 = tm1.tv_sec * 1.0E6 + tm1.tv_usec, t2 = tm2.tv_sec * 1.0E6 + ....;
```

Comment: Тут нужно быть вниметельным: или точность или переполнение. Либо явно умножать на `10e6` (или `1000000.0`). Плюс в вашем примере вы `usec` зачем-то умножаете ещё :) хотя нужно  `sec`. В любом случае - чисто теоретически при умножении можно выйти за разрядную сетку, тогда нужно: `tm1.tv_sec + tm1.tv_usec / 10e6`, но тут теряется точность. Хотя... намного ли: `usec` кодирует, по сути, дробную часть секунды с точностью до одной миллионной, double тут должно хватить за глаза.

Comment: Кстати, разницу можно сделать даже проще конкретно для данной структуры:
`secAB  = usecA > usecB ? (secA - secB) : (secA - secB - 1);`
`usecAB = usecA > usecB ? (usecA - usecB) : (1000000 - usecB + usecA);`

Comment: @MonahTuk, конечно, умножать надо секунды... и лучше сразу в плавающей арифметике.

Comment: `double` тут не совсем подойдёт: он 64 бит, ровно как и `tv_sec` (хотя там может быть что угодно, по большей части). `tv_usec` может иметь максимальное значение 999999. На него нужно 20 бит, это как запаковать 64 бита и 20 бит в 64 бита - что-то где-то потеряется. Как минимум, `time_t` может хранить число секунд с начала эпохи, а это уже 1463671291 (было несколько секунд назад :)), если помножить на 1e16 - уже выходит за пределы 64 бит.

Comment: @MonahTuk, тут imho Вы ошиблись. Пока ничего не теряем. Мантисса (ЕМНИП) в double 52 бита. Умножаем-то на 10^6. Т.о. 32 бита (а сейчас пока еще 31) грубо говоря сдвигаем на 20. Все влезает. И даже 32 бита (т.е. еще 69 лет после 2038-го) тоже не вызовут тут потери точности.

Comment: Не совсем. Вот число секунд, что я привёл выше: `1463671291`, ЕМНИП, но в double оно будет представлено как 1.463671291, соответственно у нас ещё 10^9 будет добавлено, при умножении на 10^6 вообще станет 10^15, а это уже в мантису не лезет. Даже если она 64 бита. Сегодня почитаю ещё про представление чисел с плавающей точкой, но вроде именно так и будет.

Comment: Все биты числа 1463671291 окажутся в мантиссе (52 бита). И 9  в порядке (11 бит). После умножения на 10^6 мантисса не изменится, а порядок будет 15. (на самом деле там будут [немного другие биты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), но суть та же)